# Как остановить вращение в нужном месте?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, делаю колесо фортуны, вращение примитивно:

`angle += 10 * speed;`

Замедление или ускорение тоже обычное:

```
if(play){
  speed += 0.1;
}

if(stop) speed -= 0.1;
```

speed = Math.min(1,Math.max(0, speed));
Но появилась делема, нужно либо плавно остановить в нужном сегменте, либо наоборот, не останавливать на нежелательных сегментах. Уже весь рунет обшарил, пытался сам чет нахимичить, но не чего не выходит.

Нашел типа такого примера:

`var speed=  1 -   ( (angle-EndAngle) % 6.28318531 ) / 6.28318531 ;`

Вроде как останавливает на нужной секции, но делает это быстро и с рывком(

Comment: Могу ошибаться: если отсутствует `Math.random`, то это уже не колесо фортуны.

Comment: _плавно остановить в нужном сегменте, либо наоборот, не останавливать на нежелательных сегментах_ это что за нечестные игры такие?

Comment: Сказали сделать, не скажу же я им что это нечестно и делать не буду))

Comment: Колесо - просто картинка или происходит вращения отдельных сегментов?

Comment: Картинка, сегмент я могу вычислить в градусы, например нужно остановить на 60 градусах из 360, колесо крутится постоянно до тех пор, пока юзер не нажмет остановить, в этот момент оно может быть повернуто скажем на 20 градусов, нужно плавно остановить сделал хотя бы 5 полных оборотов